# GitHub actions $GITHUB_WORKSPACE envar lists empty dir why?

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to print content of the current working directory `$PWD` or `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` with my debug job. My expectation is to see the directory's content. Unfortunately, it returns no content.

**Results**

```sh
Run ls -la $PWD
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker 4096 Apr 19 19:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 runner docker 4096 Apr 19 19:42 ..
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker 4096 Apr 19 19:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 runner docker 4096 Apr 19 19:42 ..
```

**.github/workflows/debug.yaml**

```yaml
name: Debug
on: [push, workflow_dispatch]
jobs:
  debug:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
     - name: Print current working dir
       run: |
         ls -la $PWD
         ls -la $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Please add `uses: actions/checkout@v2` as the first step in your workflow.

```yaml
name: Debug
on: [push, workflow_dispatch]
jobs:
  debug:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v2
     - name: Print current working dir
       run: |
         ls -la $PWD
         ls -la $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
```

Comment: Hi @Lukasz. Did you forget to accept your own answer?